# UIView: how to do non-destructive drawing?

Tags: iphone, uiview, drawing, cgbitmapcontextcreate, off-screen

My original question:

> I'm creating a simple drawing
>   application and need to be able to
>   draw over existing, previously drawn content in my `drawRect`.
>   What is the proper way to draw on top of existing content
>   without entirely replacing it?

Based on answers received here and elsewhere, here is the deal.

1. You should be prepared to redraw the
   entire rectangle whenever `drawRect`
   is called.
2. You **cannot** prevent the contents from being erased by doing the following:

   `[self setClearsContextBeforeDrawing: NO];`

   This is merely a hint to the graphics engine that there is no point in having it pre-clear the view for you, since you will likely need to re-draw the whole area anyway.  It may prevent your view from being automatically erased, **but you cannot depend on it**.
3. To draw on top of your view without erasing, do your drawing to an off-screen bitmap context (which is never cleared by the system.)  Then in your `drawRect`, copy from this off-screen buffer to the view.

Example:

```
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder*) coder {    
     if (self = [super initWithCoder: coder]) {
         self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         CGSize size = self.frame.size;
         drawingContext = [self createDrawingBufferContext: size];
     }

     return self;
 }

- (CGContextRef) createOffscreenContext: (CGSize) size  {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height, 8, size.width*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    return context;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect) rect {    
    UIGraphicsPushContext(drawingContext);
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(drawingContext); 
    UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    [uiImage drawInRect: rect];
    [uiImage release];
 }
```

**TODO**: can anyone optimize the `drawRect` so that only the (usually tiny) modified rectangle region is used for the copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fairly common to draw everything in an offscreen image, and simply display this image when drawing the screen.  You can read: [Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE).

Comment: Hmm, that reference seems to be C code.  When I tried adding it to my Objective-C class the simulator crashes (along with the debugger, sadly).

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is Quartz, which is supported on the iPhone.  You've probably done something wrong...  Care to show us what you've done?

Comment: Sure.  My drawRect() calls the "flag drawing" code from the example cited.  I have copy/pasted it to: http://pastebin.com/m68230dcd

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant.  You should create a single layer context in which you would render your primitives (using Quartz functions).  From what I've seen, your creating a new context for every shape.

Comment: I got this working, thanks.  It's still a little slow copying from UIView -> UIImage -> UIView.  I suspect I can speed it up if I can figure out how to copy only the (small) sub-rectangle that actually changed, rather than copying the entire view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**On optimizing drawRect**

Try this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(drawingContext);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), cgImage);
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}
```

After that you should also comment these lines in your code:

```
//CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
//CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
```

Also created [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043972/quartz-2d-draw-from-a-cgcontext-to-another-cgcontext) to be sure that it's the optimal way.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a better method than I've been using. That is, in a touches event I make a copy of the view about to be updated. Then in drawRect I take that image and draw it to the view and make my other view changes at the same time.

But this seems inefficient but the only way I figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This prevents your view from being erased before drawRect is done:

```
[self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

Also, I find it is better to do all the drawing in the drawRect method (unless you have a good reason not to).  Drawing offscreen and transferring takes more time and adds more complexity then simply drawing everything once.