# Quartz 2D: draw from a CGContext to another CGContext

Tags: iphone, macos, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d, cgcontext

I have a CGBitmapContext (*bitmapContext*) and I would like to draw some rectangle part (*rect*) of it to the current CGContext (*context*).

Right now I do that way:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
CGContextClipToRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), cgImage);
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

**Is it optimal? What is the best way to do it?**

Answer (score 2):

The alternative seems to be to create a sub-image, which I can only imagine to be less optimal.