# Why on iPad, self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO; won't make the drawRect not clear itself before drawing

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a `TestView` inherited from `UIView`, and everything is drawn on the screen using its `drawRect` method.

But if I don't want `drawRect` to clear the view before drawing, I used

```
self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;  
self.opaque = NO;   // also added because the doc says the rect 
                    //   passed to drawRect will be filled with 
                    //   background color first if it is set to YES
```

in the `initWithFrame` method.

The `drawRect` method is invoked by using

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

in the `ViewController` event handler. (for touchesMoved events)

But still, everything is cleared before anything is drawn?  How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/865636/276656) answers your question. From the answer:

> You cannot prevent the contents from being erased by doing the following:
>
> [self setClearsContextBeforeDrawing: NO];
>
> This is merely a hint to the graphics engine that there is no point in having it pre-clear the view for you, since you will likely need to re-draw the whole area anyway. It may prevent your view from being automatically erased, but you cannot depend on it.

Comment: good... this is an important concept... I think back in the old days when I was doing Win32 programming, I could draw directly on the screen... let me check if this is possible on iOS