# On iPhone and iPad, can we draw anything without using drawRect?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

It seems that the standard way to draw dots, lines, circles, and Bezier paths is to draw them in inside of `drawRect`.  We don't directly call `drawRect`, but just let iOS call it and we can use `[self setNeedsDisplay]` to tell iOS to try to call `drawRect` when it can...

It also seems that we cannot rely on

```
[self setClearsContextBeforeDrawing: NO];
```

to not clear the background of the view before calling `drawRect`.  Some details are in this question: [UIView: how to do non-destructive drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865636/uiview-how-to-do-non-destructive-drawing)

How about directly drawing on the screen -- without putting those code in `drawRect`.  For example, in `ViewController.m`, have some code that directly draw dots, lines, circles on the screen.  Is that possible?

Comment: Of course it is possile when you don't use UIKit drawing at all and instead draw using OpenGL ES or a higher level framework like Cocos2D.

Comment: it is?  what about just using iOS frameworks?  It maybe like Win32 able to draw anything when not in the redraw function (when any rectangle region got "invalidated")

Comment: And do you have to rely on Cocos2D or OpenGL ES to do it?  Frameworks from Apple's iOS won't do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having to drop into OpenGL, the closest you can do to get around the erasure is to convert the context as an image using something like [CGBitmapContextCreateImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreateImage). From there, you can retain the image in memory (or write it to disk if necessary), and then when you redraw the view, you first draw this original image into the context and then overlay it with new content.