# Drawing cumulatively to an image - really?

Tags: ios, image, graphics, draw, paint

I'm drawing beziers and rather than memorize every bezier ever and re-draw it every frame,  I'm occasionally taking a picture of the image with:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view: (CGRect)theBounds
  {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theBounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return img;
 }
```

Then I draw the image at the beginning of every drawRect, add new paths as they come in, occasionally take another picture, and repeat.

Is there a better way?  It's working but I feels 'stupid.'

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is:
Is there a better way to have a bitmap accumulate bezier paths without iOS discarding it at the end of every display loop. 

Such a bitmap would need each path stroked once and only once.

You know, like a CSS canvas element...

Answer (score 0):

Ahaaa layer context.
That's all you had to say.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGLayer/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

BTW this is better, although I disagree with the phrase "non destructive."  I wish I had found the below at the start of my project, but I never would have searched for "Non destructive."   Although, who would ever search for "Cumulatively?"  lol me no smartest

[UIView: how to do non-destructive drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865636/uiview-how-to-do-non-destructive-drawing)