# Effect of UIView coordinate system on circular version of UIProgressView

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, cgcontext, uiprogressview

I need a class derived from `UIView` that indicates progress by filling an increasingly large sector of a circle (as progress goes from 0 to 1 its angle should grow by 2 PI). It's like a circular version of `UIProgressView`.

The following code does not yet quite do the job: it produces increasingly many small sectors stacked in a flickering zebra pattern. Presumably the code is messing up its coordinates with UIView [flipping](https://www.google.com/search?q=uiview%20coordinate%20system&source=lnms&tbm=isch) its coordinate system, with [`CGContextAddArc`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextAddArc)´s (apparently) counter-intuitive definition of "clockwise", etc.

What's the reason for the misbehavior and how can it be fixed?

```
#define PERCENTAGE_TO_RADIANS(PERCENTAGE) ((PERCENTAGE) * 2 * M_PI - M_PI_2)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSAssert(!self.opaque,                     nil);
    NSAssert(!self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing, nil);

    CGSize  size   = self.bounds.size;
    CGPoint center = [self.superview convertPoint:self.center toView:self];

    NSAssert(size.width == size.height, nil);
    NSAssert((self.progress >= 0) && (self.progress <= 1), nil);

    NSAssert(PERCENTAGE_TO_RADIANS(0   ) == -M_PI_2   , nil); //   0% progress corresponds to north
    NSAssert(PERCENTAGE_TO_RADIANS(0.25) == 0         , nil); //  25% progress corresponds to east
    NSAssert(PERCENTAGE_TO_RADIANS(0.5 ) == M_PI_2    , nil); //  50% progress corresponds to south
    NSAssert(PERCENTAGE_TO_RADIANS(0.75) == M_PI      , nil); //  75% progress corresponds to west
    NSAssert(PERCENTAGE_TO_RADIANS(1   ) == 3 * M_PI_2, nil); // 100% progress corresponds to north

    CGFloat x          = center.x;
    CGFloat y          = center.y;
    CGFloat radius     = size.width / 2.0;
    CGFloat startAngle = self.lastAngle;
    CGFloat endAngle   = PERCENTAGE_TO_RADIANS(self.progress);
    int     clockwise  = 0;

    if (self.progress > 0) {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.sectorTintColor.CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);

        NSAssert(startAngle <= endAngle, nil);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
        CGContextAddArc(context, x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise);
        CGContextClosePath(context);

        CGContextFillPath(context);

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    self.lastAngle = endAngle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing you need to know is that positive Y is down, which makes the angles and the clockwise direction non-intuitive.  You have two choices, either just go with it, or flip the Y-axis before drawing anything.  In the sample code below, I took the latter approach.

The `drawRect` method is not accumulative. In other words, you are required to draw the entire sector on each call to `drawRect`. Hence there is no reason to keep track of the start angle, you should always start at angle PI/2 and draw the whole sector.

There is no need to save and restore the graphics state. The graphics context is created new each time `drawRect` is called.

The UIColor class has `set`, `setFill`, and `setStroke` methods that allow you to change fill and stroke colors without using CGColors.

With all that in mind, here's what the code looks like, assuming that `self.progress` is a number between 0.0 and 1.0

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if ( self.progress <= 0 || self.progress > 1.0 )
        return;

    CGFloat x = self.bounds.size.width  / 2.0;
    CGFloat y = self.bounds.size.height / 2.0;
    CGFloat r = (x <= y) ? x : y;

    CGFloat angle = M_PI_2 - self.progress * 2.0 * M_PI;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // fix the y axis, so that positive y is up
    CGContextScaleCTM( context, 1.0, -1.0 );
    CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0, -self.bounds.size.height );

    // draw the pie shape
    [self.sectorTintColor setFill];
    CGContextMoveToPoint( context, x, y );
    CGContextAddArc( context, x, y, r, M_PI_2, angle, YES );
    CGContextClosePath( context );

    CGContextFillPath( context );
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thx. Could you please clarify one more point? I thought `drawRect:` is accumulative if the view's `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` is set to `NO`. But you are suggesting that if that is so the background view's context won't be cleared, but the view's own view (within `rect`) will always be cleared  before `drawRect:` is called regardless, right?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865636/uiview-how-to-do-non-destructive-drawing) was helpful re `clearsContextBeforeDrawing`: "You cannot prevent the contents from being erased by doing the following: `[self setClearsContextBeforeDrawing: NO];` This is merely a hint to the graphics engine that there is no point in having it pre-clear the view for you, since you will likely need to re-draw the whole area anyway. It may prevent your view from being automatically erased, but you cannot depend on it."

Comment: Ah yes, that explains it nicely. Now all we need is the `preservesContextFromPreviousDrawing` property :)